# Finding a proof for a composite number statement

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I've been trying to solve this specific proof problem, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to start with the proof.

Here it is:

> For all $a\in\mathbb Z_+$ with $a > 3$ , $a^2 - 4$ is composite

Comment: Can you factor the difference of two squares?

Comment: Factorize $a^2-4$. Can you do it? Or try and divide $a^2-4$ by $a+2$. This should be easy if you know polynomial division.

Comment: The third binomial formula applies here. If you have the factors, just show that both are greater than $1$, and you are done.

Comment: Wow was really thinking hard about this, lol, figured it out. Any multiple of two numbers will be in return divisible by those numbers. So this statement is always valid. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a>3$ we get that $a-2>1$. Now, $a^2-4=(a+2)(a-2)$ and both the factors are greater than $1$, hence it is a composite number.